# Xcode does not show what is covered by tests

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I know that the Xcode should highlight in green and number how many tests have been written for my method and in red where there are no tests.

Where can I enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click on the "Adjust Editor Options" button (right hand side of the currently opened Xcode minitab), then you'll see the "Code Coverage" option.

[image: code coverage]